# how to print the "$" in echo statement in php?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php
            $array1 = array("The price of Mac"=>2000, "One year refundable"=>"Yes", "24/7 support"=>"Yes");
            foreach ($array1 as $index => $value) {
                if(is_int($value)) {
                    echo "{$index} is ${$value}, ";
                } else {
                    echo "{$index} is {$value}, ";
                }
            }
            echo "</ br>";
        ?>
```

but the $2000 did not show up, when I put a space in the line

```
if(is_int($value)) {
                        echo "{$index} is $ {$value}, ";
                    }
```

the `$ 2000` show up, but how to output $2000?

Answer (score 7):

```
echo "{$index} is \${$value}, ";
```

Comment: Do we need braces here?

Comment: @Mr.Alien No, the braces are optional.

Comment: Ya that's what I thought as there is no array here

Answer (score 2):

use

```
echo $index. ' is $'.$value.', ';
```

or

```
echo "{$index} is &#36;{$value}, ";
```

or

```
echo "{$index} is \${$value}, ";
```

Comment: thank you, in the second solution, what does "#36" mean?

Comment: You're welcome! It's the ASCII-Code for the Dollar-symbol. If you need more symbols, check this table: http://www.webmaster-knowhow.com/tabellen/html-ascii-codes-tabelle/